# Can a predicate be explicitly defined?

Tags: scala

Below object filters and maps a case class :

```
object PartialTest extends App {

  case class c()
  val l = List(c)

  l.filter({ case c => true })
  l.map({ case c => true })

}
```

Can the predicate for `filter` and `map` be explicitly defined ?

Something like : 
`val myPredicate = { case c => true };` ?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Sure—`filter` and `map` are just ordinary methods that take a function:

```
scala> case class C()
defined class C

scala> val l = List(C())
l: List[C] = List(C())

scala> val alwaysTrue: C => Boolean = Function.const(true)
alwaysTrue: C => Boolean = <function1>

scala> l.filter(alwaysTrue)
res0: List[C] = List(C())
```

(Note that I've changed a couple of things for idiomaticity and since you probably don't want a list of the case class's companion object.)

If you want to use the partial function syntax (with `case`), you can do that as well:

```
scala> val anotherVersion: C => Boolean = {
     |   case _ => true
     | }
anotherVersion: C => Boolean = <function1>

scala> l.filter(anotherVersion)
res1: List[C] = List(C())
```

There are dozens of ways to define functions in Scala, and all of them will work, as long as you end up with a function with the appropriate input and output types.

Comment: thanks, my initial thought was that 'def fun = { case c => true }' should compile but this is not creating the required input and output types...

Comment: @blue-sky You just need to specify the type of `c`: `c: C => true` (note lack of `case`). This way the compiler knows the argument type, and it can trivially infer the result type. So specifying expected type, as in the answer, isn't required.

Answer (score 3):

Yes, the following compiles:

```
object PartialTest extends App {

case class C()
val l = List(C())

val myPredicate: PartialFunction[C, Boolean] = {
  case cv: C => true
}

l.filter(myPredicate)

l.map(myPredicate)
```

}

Answer (score 2):

The problem with your idea `val myPredicate = { case c => true }` is quite simple: in order for an anonymous function to compile, the compiler needs to know the argument type(s). It can be specified explicitly: `val myPredicate = { c: C => true }`. Otherwise, the compiler needs an *expected type*, which can be given either by using the function as a method argument (which happens in your original code), or by specifying the type of `myPredicate` (as in the other 2 answers). This is described precisely in http://www.scala-lang.org/files/archive/spec/2.11/06-expressions.html#anonymous-functions.